# How to include a variable within M language PowerQuery

Tags: microsoft-excel, power-query, microsoft-excel-365

In Excel365 I am trying to build a query that includes some POST data, and I have it all working until I try to make those values variables that come from named cells in my Workbook.  In the example below, I have the value for `ApiKey` variable **successfully populated** in the second line, but when I get to the line that would add it to the `myContent` list, I cannot figure out how to insert that value.  How do I designate that "ApiKey" is a variable in "M Language" in line 5 so that it is not interpreted as a string but is still enclosed in quotation marks?

```
let
    ApiKey = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="ApiKey"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],
    BaseURL = "https://www.example.com/api",
    myContent = "{
        ""key"": ""ApiKey"",
        ""datarequest"": ""all""
        }",
    myData=Json.Document(myContent),
    Source = Json.Document( 
        Web.Contents(
            BaseURL,
            [
                Headers=[#"Content-Type" = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"],
                Content=Text.ToBinary(Uri.BuildQueryString(myData))
            ]
        )
    )
    
in
    Source
```

If I "hardcode" the API key into the content list like this, everything works...but I need it to be the value of my stored variable:

```
 myContent = "{
        ""key"": ""H5t9sdf7K-FAKEAPIKEY-LHkeQr2"",
        ""datarequest"": ""all""
        }",
```

Things I have tried include:

```
 myContent = "{
        ""key"": """&ApiKey&""",
        ""datarequest"": ""all""
        }",
```

and

```
 myContent = "{
        ""key"": ""@ApiKey"",
        ""datarequest"": ""all""
        }",
```

but the [documentation I have found from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/m-spec-operators) is pretty lacking (from my perspective)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure this will work as not used API keys in a PQ.

Use a function to grab your named range data.
I've called the function `fGetNamedRange`:

```
let GetNamedRange=(NamedRange) => 
    let
        name = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name=NamedRange]}[Content],
        value = name{0}[Column1]
    in
        value
in GetNamedRange
```

Pass your named range into your query:

```
let
    myContent = "{
        ""key"": """ & Text.From(fGetNamedRange("MyNamedRange")) & """,
        ""datarequest"": ""all""
        }"

in
    myContent
```

[image]

After reading your question again and seeing your workbook reference is looking at ApiKey, try:

```
let
    ApiKey = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="ApiKey"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],
    BaseURL = "https://www.example.com/api",
    myContent = "{
        ""key"": """ & Text.From(ApiKey) & """,
        ""datarequest"": ""all""
        }",
    myData=Json.Document(myContent),
    Source = Json.Document( 
        Web.Contents(
            BaseURL,
            [
                Headers=[#"Content-Type" = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"],
                Content=Text.ToBinary(Uri.BuildQueryString(myData))
            ]
        )
    )
    
in
    Source
```

Comment: Your second solution WORKED!  Text.From(ApiKey)  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Splitting out bits of code into different queries can really help with troubleshooting later, rather than cramming all into some super-long clever M code. My approach for this scenario would be:

Create a table in Excel with your API key in. "Get data" from that table. Where the value of the API key is shown, right click and select "Drill down". This turns the value into a value, rather than a row of a column in a table.
Rename this query as "APIKey". You can now use this just like a parameter, but it is easier for an end user to update in the Excel sheet table rather than editing PQ.

M code looks like this:

```
let
Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="ParametersTable"]}[Content],
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each [Name] = "API Key"),
Value = #"Filtered Rows"{0}[Value]
in 
Value
```

In your other code, just replace your "APIKey" with APIKey. For example, I have a test table and want to filter the Names column for values that equal the value of my APIKey (not ="APIKey"):

```
let
Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="TestTable"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Names", type text}, {"Test", type text}}),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each [Names] = APIKey) 
in 
#"Filtered Rows"
```

If you prefer to call your value API Key with spaces, then you need quotes round it, then a # to tell PQ that this is the name of a value, not a literal string - [Names] = #"API Key"

Comment: Unfortunately, that will not work.  This is actually heavily simplified code...I will ultimately be inserting a dozen or more variables into the query before it is called, in order to return a specific dataset that has been filtered from several million data points.  Further work will happen in Excel to filter and manipulate the data, but I have to get the right dataset first :-)